# Pods lifecycle when launched using cronjobs in kubernetes from spring cloud datfalow

Tags: spring, cron, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using spring cloud dataflow on kubernetes to run my batch jobs as tasks. I have put a scheduler which runs the job every hour. EVenthough in the UI I can see that there have been about 30 executions, in the kubernetes UI or terminal I can only see the pods and jobs of the last 3 executions. So I wanted to know if the scheduler deletes all the previous pods and if so how can I change that lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

Check what is your `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` in job spec. Default `successfulJobsHistoryLimit` is 3.

Ref: [Jobs History Limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits)